# Python tkinter RadioButton callback function

Tags: python, tkinter, callback, widget

This comes from a button that when pressed generates a radiobutton.  I am not able to access to the choice made with radiobutton. Everything works fine, but the output of selected function is zero.  I try using both local  and global var but the result is the same.

```
def callback_st(): # RadioButton select technology
    var = IntVar()
    m=0
    for m in range(len(un_tech)):
        Radiobutton(radio_frame, text=un_tech[m], value=m, variable=var,
                    command=selected(var)).pack(anchor=W)

def selected(var):
    print(var)
```

This doesn't work.  I solved using lambda:

```
    def selected(jst):
        global sel_technology
        sel_technology=un_tech[jst]
        print(sel_technology)

def callback_st(): #RadioButton select technology
    var_st = IntVar()
    m=0
    for m in range(len(un_tech)):
    Radiobutton(radio_frame, text=un_tech[m], value=m, variable=var_st,
                command = lambda jst=m: selected(jst)).pack(anchor=W)
```

This works as i want, but it isn't the solution that i want and i think is not the correct way. So, somebody can help me to find the right way?

Comment: Are you familiar  with the concept of local and global variables? `var` is a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

In your first try, you *call* `selected` immediately, when `var` has a value of `0`.  You avoided this with the lambda expression, but you are correct that this is an awkward workaround for the original mistake.  Make `var` global and have `selected` access it as a global.  Modifying your first code:

```
var = IntVar()
def selected():
    print(var.get())
def callback_st():
    ...
         ...command=selected...
```

If you were defining a class and methods, var would be an instance attribute instead of global.